# What is an analogous lemma?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I am given lemma 1.17.2 and asked here to find an analogous lemma

[image]

Is the "analogous lemma" just that if I have two perpendicular bisectors that lie on the angle bisector, that the two perpendicular bisectors have the same length? Not quite sure what the question means with that terminology, but that was my interpretation. If that's what the question is asking me to find and prove then it's pretty simple, but I want to make sure that I understand what I'm being asked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analogous lemma should be something like that:

*The points that are at the same distance from the two endpoints of a segment are exactly the points of the perpendicular bisector of the segment.*